# How can i send immediate Web visit notification based on custom field in Eloqua [Not Profile fields]?

Tags: eloqua

I am trying to achieve here the  instant Visitor Web notification to Eloqua user based on the Custom field which is other than profile fields ?Is anybody face the same issue earlier on setting up the Visitor notification & how you have resolved that ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Visitor profile fields are hard coded within Eloqua and there is no way to include a contact field since you cannot assume that a visitor has an existing linked contact record. This is just the nature of known vs unknown website visitors.

Thanks!